# How to locate error data when inserting data without SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table that has many columns of integer type, and it is used for inserting data from another source table that all corresponding columns are varchar.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(intCol1, intCol2, ...intColN, [OtherCols])
SELECT CAST(col1 AS int), CAST(col2 AS int),.... FROM SourceTable
```

And finally the script raised an data-level yet obscure error like 'failed to convert something to int' or 'arithmetic overflowed error by converting into int'. However since I have so many int columns and so many rows of data, it's not very likely to find where is the source of error, at least in column level.

What's more, due to some reason it is not allowed to use SSIS to redirect and find error data for my situation, only SQL script level available. Is there any solutions?

Comment: Unless you validate, you couldn't able to find erroneous data. Since you are limited to use SSIS, you need to do write a trigger on a table before insert and have a logic for checking each columns and if it didn't meet the table datatype push it into error table. #Just a thought.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: you could also write some dynamic sql using schema views to get column names and datatypes then query your source table to discover the issues.  Or rather use those views to help you construct a long statement in a where clause to test datatypes prior to insert.  Then insert records that pass the where statments match back to find the records that were not successful...or use a MERGE and when not matched insert to a failure table.......ISNUMERIC() ISDATE() LEN() DATALENGHT() etc.....

Comment: If your answer to @TabAlleman is 2012 or newer you can change your `CAST(col# AS int)` to `TRY_PARSE(col# AS int)` and you'll insert the numbers if they're valid integers otherwise it will just insert a `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to redirect error rows from an OLE DB Destination in SSIS.
Do not use fast load in the dest, configure error output to 'redirect row' instead of 'failure component', use the red arrow/data flow path to send the bad row to a derived column task, put a data viewer on the red data flow path.

That should allow you to find the specific row that is causing the issue.